# Can a Python Fabric task invoke other tasks and respect their hosts lists?

Tags: python, deployment, ssh, fabric

I have a fabfile like the following:

```
@hosts('host1')
def host1_deploy():
    """Some logic that is specific to deploying to host1"""

@hosts('host2')
def host2_deploy():
    """Some logic that is specific to deploying to host2"""

def deploy():
    """"Deploy to both hosts, each using its own logic"""
    host1_deploy()
    host2_deploy()
```

I would like to do

```
fab deploy
```

and have it be equivalent to

```
fab host1_deploy host2_deploy
```

In other words, run each of the subtasks and for each one use the list of hosts that it specifies. However, this does not work. Instead, the deploy() task wants its own list of hosts that it will propogate to all of its subtasks.

Is there a way to update the deploy() task here so it will do what I want while leaving the subtasks alone so they can be run individually?

Answer (score 31):

Since Fabric 1.3, the `execute` helper is now available to do just this. The documentation is available here: [Intelligently executing tasks with execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute).

Here is the example they use:

```
from fabric.api import run, roles, execute

env.roledefs = {
    'db': ['db1', 'db2'],
    'web': ['web1', 'web2', 'web3'],
}

@roles('db')
def migrate():
    # Database stuff here.
    pass

@roles('web')
def update():
    # Code updates here.
   pass
```

And then to run both `migrate` and `web` from another task `deploy`:

```
def deploy():
    execute(migrate)
    execute(update)
```

And this will respect the roles and hosts lists that those tasks have.

Comment: Is it possible to add the role to a class method? I use classes for fabric tasks

Comment: The link to the documentation is broken. Here is the latest: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute

Answer (score 3):

This is lame but it works as of Fabric 1.1.2

```
def host1_deploy():
    """Some logic that is specific to deploying to host1"""
    if env.host in ["host1"]:
        pass #this is only on host2

def host2_deploy():
    """Some logic that is specific to deploying to host2"""
    if env.host in ["host2"]:
        pass #this is only on host2

def deploy():
    """"Deploy to both hosts, each using its own logic"""
    host1_deploy()
    host2_deploy()
```

here's my test code:

```
@task
@roles(["prod_web","prod_workers"])
def test_multi():
    test_multi_a()
    test_multi_b()

def test_multi_a():
    if env.host in env.roledefs["prod_web"]:
        run('uname -a')

def test_multi_b():
    if env.host in env.roledefs["prod_workers"]:
        run('uname -a')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way to handle it, but you could pass both hosts to deploy(), and then in host1_deploy() and host2_deploy() check env.host:

```
def host1_deploy():
    if env.host in ['host1']:
         run(whatever1)

def host2_deploy():
    if env.host in ['host2']:
         run(whatever2)

@hosts('host1','host2')
def deploy():
    host1_deploy()
    host2_deploy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Obviously you want to replace local with `run` or `sudo`. The key is the empty `@hosts` decorator for `deploy`

```
from fabric.api import local
from fabric.decorators import hosts

@hosts('host1')
def host1_deploy():
    """Some logic that is specific to deploying to host1"""
    local('echo foo')

@hosts('host2')
def host2_deploy():
    """Some logic that is specific to deploying to host2"""
    local('echo bar')

@hosts('')
def deploy():
    """"Deploy to both hosts, each using its own logic"""
    host1_deploy()
    host2_deploy()
```