# How do you define a wrapper function in Fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

Consider this simple fabric file:

```
def wrapper():
    f1()
    f2()

@hosts([host1])
def f1():
    run('ls')

@hosts([host2])
def f2():
    run('uname')
```

By running `fab wrapper` you get a prompt for:

> No hosts found. Please specify a (single) host string for connection:

How can I make `wrapper()` ignore any hosts, and assume all sub-tasks will handle that aspect?

Comment: Hmm, just found a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346135/can-a-python-fabric-task-invoke-other-tasks-and-respect-their-hosts-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fabric issue #21](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/21) deals with this longstanding problem.

`execute()` now supports this behavior.