# Python Fabric : tricky ssh issue

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I have a system that i use to run a fabric script that executes test cases on several other client systems.(via launch_process.sh)

```
@task
@hosts('controller')
def run_script():
           run('/test/launch_process.sh')
           #below line didn't work 
           check_ps()


@task
@hosts('clients')
def check_ps():
           run('ps aux | grep myprocess')
```

when we do 
    fab run_script

it launches the process on other machines (assume machine2,machine3)
Now I would like to use 'ps' command to confirm ,the process running or not.
But check_ps() runs on 'controller' itself - not on clients.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this ?

(looking for solution ,without using passwdless login and popen or paramiko)

Comment: why do you have different arguments to @hosts() ?

Comment: Have a look here for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346135/can-a-python-fabric-task-invoke-other-tasks-and-respect-their-hosts-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric has execute() now. http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute

That'll let you do:

```
@task
@hosts('controller')
def run_script():
    run('/test/launch_process.sh')
    execute(check_ps, hosts=['client'])
```

And with that the @hosts on check_ps is still valid in the event you want to run it alone (w/o run_script())